# Where can I found software sources?

Tags: 10.04, software-sources, freebasic

I have Ubuntu 10.04. I want to upgrade it to 12.04 SO I found the following steps on [Ubuntu.com](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuDesktop#Upgrading_from_Ubuntu_10.04_LTS_to_Ubuntu_12.04_LTS). I hope that is correct way.

The first step is to go to System/Administration/**Software Sources.**

But I can not find it there. So where else can I find it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading 10.04 to 12.04 is strange idea - why don't you want to have 14.04? Anyway, upgrading such old Ubuntu release will almost certainly lead to troubles. Just make a backup of your files and use whole disk to install current version of Ubuntu - 14.04.

Comment: frankly speaking i was using 14.04 before a week. but due to my carelessness it stopped working. I had installed 14.04 from flash drive[which i have lost] I had Ubuntu 10.04 so i installed it but it had already reached EOL so i don't know what to do !! :(